# How to estimate the best fitting function to a scatter plot in R?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, model-fitting

I have scatterplot of two variables, for instance this:

```
x<-c(0.108,0.111,0.113,0.116,0.118,0.121,0.123,0.126,0.128,0.131,0.133,0.136)

y<-c(-6.908,-6.620,-5.681,-5.165,-4.690,-4.646,-3.979,-3.755,-3.564,-3.558,-3.272,-3.073)
```

and I would like to find the function that better fits the relation between these two variables.

to be precise I would like to compare the fitting of three models: `linear`, `exponential` and `logarithmic`.

I was thinking about fitting each function to my values, calculate the likelihoods in each case and compare the AIC values.

But I don't really know how or where to start. Any possible help about this would be extremely appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Tina.

Comment: Have you tried symbolic regression with the `rgp` package? If you include some sample data we can try it out. More details here: http://www.rsymbolic.org/projects/rgp/wiki/Symbolic_Regression

Comment: How basic do we have to go here? Have you read the data in? Have you done any exploratory plots? Do you at least know how to fit a linear model with the `lm` package? We're kinda stuck for level without a bit more...

Comment: thank you very much, I have added an example, I know pretty much the basics in R, but I am new when it comes to fitting models more complex than a regression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of comparing five models.  Due to the form of the first two models we are able to use `lm` to get good starting values.  (Note that models using different transforms of `y` should not be compared so we should not use `lm1` and `lm2` as comparison models but only for starting values.)  Now run an `nls` for each of the first two.   After these two models we try polynomials of various degrees in `x`.  Fortunately `lm` and `nls` use consistent `AIC` definitions (although its not necessarily true that other R model fitting functions have consistent `AIC` definitions) so we can just use `lm` for the polynomials. Finally we plot the data and fits of the first two models.

The lower the AIC the better so `nls1` is best followed by `lm3.2` following by `nls2` .

```
lm1 <- lm(1/y ~ x)
nls1 <- nls(y ~ 1/(a + b*x), start = setNames(coef(lm1), c("a", "b")))
AIC(nls1) # -2.390924

lm2 <- lm(1/y ~ log(x))
nls2 <- nls(y ~ 1/(a + b*log(x)), start = setNames(coef(lm2), c("a", "b")))
AIC(nls2) # -1.29101

lm3.1 <- lm(y ~ x) 
AIC(lm3.1) # 13.43161

lm3.2 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))
AIC(lm3.2) # -1.525982

lm3.3 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 3))
AIC(lm3.3) # 0.1498972

plot(y ~ x)

lines(fitted(nls1) ~ x, lty = 1) # solid line
lines(fitted(nls2) ~ x, lty = 2) # dashed line
```

[image]

ADDED a few more models and subsequently fixed them up and changed notation. Also to follow up on Ben Bolker's comment we can replace `AIC` everywhere above with `AICc` from the AICcmodavg package.

Answer (score 7):

I would begin by an explantory plots, something like this :

```
x<-c(0.108,0.111,0.113,0.116,0.118,0.121,0.123,0.126,0.128,0.131,0.133,0.136)
y<-c(-6.908,-6.620,-5.681,-5.165,-4.690,-4.646,-3.979,-3.755,-3.564,-3.558,-3.272,-3.073)
dat <- data.frame(y=y,x=x)
library(latticeExtra)
library(grid)
xyplot(y ~ x,data=dat,par.settings = ggplot2like(),
       panel = function(x,y,...){
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
       })+
  layer(panel.smoother(y ~ x, method = "lm"), style =1)+  ## linear
  layer(panel.smoother(y ~ poly(x, 3), method = "lm"), style = 2)+  ## cubic
  layer(panel.smoother(y ~ x, span = 0.9),style=3)  + ### loeess
  layer(panel.smoother(y ~ log(x), method = "lm"), style = 4)  ## log
```

[image]

looks like you need a cubic model.

```
 summary(lm(y~poly(x,3),data=dat))

Residual standard error: 0.1966 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9831, Adjusted R-squared: 0.9767 
F-statistic: 154.8 on 3 and 8 DF,  p-value: 2.013e-07
```

Comment: +1 that's very good, how about the AIC values? A method for exploring the smoothers in `ggplot` is here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/smooths.htm

Comment: thank you very much, I have problems to install the grid package, I guess it's this one you mean: http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/grid/grid.html (I have a mac).

Comment: Yes. grid of Paul murrell(bless him).No need to install it , just load it , it is distributed with R like it is mentioned in the link you give.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by reading the classic paper by Box and Cox on transformations.  They discuss how to compare transformations and how to find meaningful transformations within a set or family of potential transforms.  The log transform and linear model are special cases of the Box-Cox family.

And as @agstudy said, always plot the data as well.