# rgp (R genetic programming) package - not able to do regression

Tags: r, regression, rgp

I am trying to do non-linear regression using R genetic package (rgp) using technique used here: [Fitting a curve to specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190883/fitting-a-curve-to-specific-data/15050715#15050715) (see second method). I am using R package `drc` for `heartrate` data:

```
library(drc)

head(heartrate)
#  pressure   rate
#1    50.85 348.76
#2    54.92 344.45
#3    59.23 343.05
#4    61.91 332.92
#5    65.22 315.31
#6    67.79 313.50

library(rgp)

res <- symbolicRegression(rate ~ pressure, data=heartrate)

(symbreg <- res$population[[which.min(sapply(res$population, res$fitnessFunction))]])
#function (pressure) 
#pressure + (pressure/0.853106872646055 + pressure)

ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data=heartrate, aes(pressure,rate), size = 3) +
    geom_line(data=data.frame(symbx=heartrate$pressure, 
                              symby=sapply(heartrate$pressure, symbreg)), 
              aes(symbx, symby), colour = "red")
```

However, the resulting regression line that I am getting is clearly incorrect. The distribution of data points indicate a curvilinear relation with rate reducing as pressure increases (inverse association). However, the regression line generated is linear and in the wrong direction.

[image]

Where is the error?

Edit:

Using increased steps as suggested by @cuttlefish44 in comments:

```
res = symbolicRegression(rate ~ pressure, data = heartrate, stopCondition = makeStepsStopCondition(45000))

(symbreg <- res$population[[which.min(sapply(res$population, res$fitnessFunction))]])
#function (pressure) 
#exp(exp(exp(cos(cos(-9.23878724686801/pressure)))))
```

It took 8 minutes to complete. The plot is:

[image]

The direction of regression line is better than above (!), but it indicates that it will take a really long time to reach the obvious direction. The regression line with the function obtained by @cuttlefish44 is also similar and not a really good fit.

Comment: Maybe the default value of `stopCondition`, `makeTimeStopCondition(5)`, is too short in your case ?  `symbolicRegression(rate ~ pressure, data = heartrate, stopCondition = makeStepsStopCondition(45000))` gave me `symbreg; function (pressure) exp(exp(exp(exp(tan(6.91310722380877/pressure - sin(0.932394750416279)) * cos(exp(sin(-9.12634917534888)))))))`

Comment: I have added the result with this in question above.

Answer (score -1):

You may have already read this but I think your answer is hidden somewhere inside [this introduction to RGP package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgp/vignettes/rgp_introduction.pdf) written by Oliver Flasch.

I don't know anything about `rgp`package but if you only want a linear regression, why don't you use `lm()`function from the base package ?

At least you would be able to estimate parameters of β<sub>0</sub> and  β<sub>1</sub> for Ordinary least squares regression :

rate = β<sub>1</sub>*pressure + β<sub>0</sub>

```
     linear.model <- lm(rate ~ pressure, data=heartrate)

     ggplot(data=heartrate, aes(x=pressure,y=rate)) + 
         geom_point() + 
         geom_smooth(method="lm", col="red")
```

[linear regression with ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZkwu.jpg)

You can access the coeficcients with `linear.model$coefficients`

You can still manipulate the predicted values with `linear.model$fitted.values`

You have access to the residual with : `linear.model$residuals`

If you want to fit the curve with more accuracy the linear model might be not sufficient, you can try `glm`, or a polynomial regression and select the best model with AIC or BIC criteria.

Comment: I do not want linear regression and that is exactly why I am using rgp package. I have seen this Introduction to rgp pdf file but there also very similar method is recommended. Why don't you use rgp package and try to get a proper result.

Comment: Sorry I didn't take a look at your profile you're right, did you see all the warnings indicating you the generation of NAN during the process of symbolicRegression ?

Comment: That's a really good point. I had not seen warnings() earlier. You should put this in the answer and how to correct this rather than how to do linear regression.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that I am trying to do non-linear regression.