# Curve Fitting in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

Any resources for curve fitting in R? 
I came across https://systatsoftware.com/products/sigmaplot/product-uses/sigmaplot-products-uses-curve-fitting-using-sigmaplot/

Any similar recommendations or libraries in R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi There are not one but several ways to do curve fitting in R. You could start with something as simple as below

```
x <- c(32,64,96,118,126,144,152.5,158)
#make y as response variable
y <- c(99.5,104.8,108.5,100,86,64,35.3,15)    
plot(x,y,pch=19)
```

This should give you the below plot. Eyeballing the curve tells us we can fit some nice polynomial curve here.

[image]

Now we could fit our curve(s) on the data below:

```
linMod  <- lm(y~x)
#second degree polynomial model
linMod2 <- lm(y~poly(x,2,raw=TRUE))
#third degree polynomial model
linMod3 <- lm(y~poly(x,3,raw=TRUE))
#fourth degree polynomial model
linMod4 <- lm(y~poly(x,4,raw=TRUE))
#generate new data in range of 50 numbers starting from 30 and ending at 160
newData <- seq(30,160, length=50)
plot(x,y,pch=19,ylim=c(0,150))
lines(newData, predict(linMod, data.frame(x=newData)), col="red")
lines(newData, predict(linMod2, data.frame(x=newData)), col="green")
lines(newData, predict(linMod3, data.frame(x=newData)), col="blue")
lines(newData, predict(linMod4, data.frame(x=newData)), col="purple")
```

Giving us:

[image]

This is just a simple illustration of curve fitting in R. There are tons of tutorials available out there, perhaps you could start looking here:

- http://www.css.cornell.edu/faculty/dgr2/teach/R/R_CurveFit.pdf
- https://rpubs.com/carlmart/228874
- [Fitting a curve to specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190883/fitting-a-curve-to-specific-data)