# How to do a regression using a specific model in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataset, which I want to adjust to the following model and get the values of parameters **a** and **b**

[image: $$ dan $$]

```
x <- c(31.56750292, 26.91965284, 23.40296193, 15.63530835, 0)
y <- c(1.132561597, 1.340922478, 1.284691753, 1.610823279, 0)

DF <- data.frame(x, y)

my_model <- lm(y ~ (a * b * x)/(1 + (b * x)))

summary(my_model)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you're looking for `stats::nls`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190883/fitting-a-curve-to-specific-data/15050715#15050715

Comment: I think you will need more data for `nls`. I can't get a fit with only 5 observations and 2 parameters. Adding another point, e.g. x=8, y= 1.1 gives a fit for `DF.nls <- nls(y ~ (a * b * x)/(1 + (b * x)), data=DF, start=list(a=1, b=1))`.